# Byte Array with control characters to string

Tags: c#

So I've found a few examples but none that are *exactly* as I want it (close though)

example of what i'm looking for

```
byte[] array = { 0x02, 0x64, 0x40, 0x40, 0x03 };
string text = SomeMagicalMethod(array);
//displays <STX>FOO<ETX>
```

At one point I had a dictionary with the non-printable character values and the <...> stuff in it, but combining the 2 strings is killing my head. I currently have this, but it ASCIIEncoding takes out all Control characters.

```
public static void Add(this TextBox tb, byte[] array)
{
  string input = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(array);

  Regex.Replace( input     ,
                 @"\p{Cc}" ,
                 a => string.Format( "[{0:X2}]" , (byte)a.Value[0] )
               ) ;
  Add(tb, input);

}

public static void Add(this TextBox tb, string text)
{
  text += ENTER;
  tb.Dispatcher.Invoke( DispatcherPriority.Background,
    new Action(delegate() { tb.Text += text; })
    );
}
```

**EDIT**
Using NUnit i ran the answered codes against these tests. The last one has one value that is out of the scope of 0x7F. Although the code this will be used in should NOT have that, it is better to be safe then sorry.

```
[TestFixture]
public class StringExtensionsTest
{
    [Test]
    public void SingleByteControlCharacterTest()
    {
        AssertSingleByte(0x00, "<NUL>"); AssertSingleByte(0x01, "<SOH>");
        AssertSingleByte(0x02, "<STX>"); AssertSingleByte(0x03, "<ETX>");
        AssertSingleByte(0x04, "<EOT>"); AssertSingleByte(0x05, "<ENQ>");
        AssertSingleByte(0x06, "<ACK>"); AssertSingleByte(0x07, "<BEL>");
        AssertSingleByte(0x08, "<BS>" ); AssertSingleByte(0x09, "<HT>" );
        AssertSingleByte(0x0A, "<LF>" ); AssertSingleByte(0x0B, "<VT>" );
        AssertSingleByte(0x0C, "<FF>" ); AssertSingleByte(0x0D, "<CR>" );
        AssertSingleByte(0x0E, "<SO>" ); AssertSingleByte(0x0F, "<SI>" );

        AssertSingleByte(0x10, "<DLE>"); AssertSingleByte(0x11, "<DC1>");
        AssertSingleByte(0x12, "<DC2>"); AssertSingleByte(0x13, "<DC3>");
        AssertSingleByte(0x14, "<DC4>"); AssertSingleByte(0x15, "<NAK>");
        AssertSingleByte(0x16, "<SYN>"); AssertSingleByte(0x17, "<ETB>");
        AssertSingleByte(0x18, "<CAN>"); AssertSingleByte(0x19, "<EM>" );
        AssertSingleByte(0x1A, "<SUB>"); AssertSingleByte(0x1B, "<ESC>");
        AssertSingleByte(0x1C, "<FS>" ); AssertSingleByte(0x1D, "<GS>" );
        AssertSingleByte(0x1E, "<RS>" ); AssertSingleByte(0x1F, "<US>" );
        AssertSingleByte(0x7F, "<DEL>");
    }
    private void AssertSingleByte(byte value, string expected)
    {
        byte[] array = new byte[]{value};
        var actual = array.asciiOctets2String();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "Didn't print the epxected result");
    }

    [Test]
    public void SingleCharacterTest()
    {
        for (byte i = 0x20; i < 0x7F; i++) 
        {
            AssertSingleByte(i, char.ToString((char)i));
        }
    }

    [Test]
    public void SimpleTestTogether()
    {
        byte[] array = {0x02, 0x46,0x4F, 0x4F, 0x03};
        string expected = "<STX>FOO<ETX>";
        string actual = array.asciiOctets2String();
        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "Simple test failed");
    }
    [Test]
    public void BigTest()
    {
        byte[] array = {
            0x00, 0x7F, 0x03, 0x52, 0x00, 0x00, 0x2F, 0x5F, 0x20, 0x0F, 0x43, 0x41, 0x52, 0x44, 0x48, 0x4F,
            0x4C, 0x44, 0x45, 0x52, 0x2F, 0x56, 0x49, 0x53, 0x41, 0x9F, 0x1F, 0x07, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30, 0x30,
            0x30, 0x30, 0x30};
        string expected = "<NUL><DEL><ETX>R<NUL><NUL>/_ <SI>CARDHOLDER/VISA?<US><BEL>0000000";
        string actual = array.asciiOctets2String();

        Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, "BigTest Failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: I 'm not sure what you want -- to transform the byte 0x02 to the string of length 5 `"<STX>"`?

Comment: Note that `0x64 0x40 0x40` in ASCII is actually `"d@@"`, `0x46 0x4F 0x4F` is `FOO`.

Comment: It isn't true to say that "ASCIIEncoding takes out all Control characters" - simply: it is keeping them *as control characters* - not human readable

Comment: @p.s.w.g thank you for that correction. I was in a rush when i was leaving work and read my printout incorrectly. :) what a long day.

Comment: @MarcGravell interesting. I assumed that it did take them out because in the code I have posted it should have replaced a control character with the string version with square brackets around it. IE <STX> would have been [02]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The C# ASCII converter junks any character outside of the 7-bit ASCII range (0x00–0x7F).

If you have code points outside that range, then you don't have ASCII. Use the appropriate encoding (like UTF-8).

If you know that your byte array is ASCII (meaning that it **only** contains the code points 0x00–0x7F), then you don't need the converter at all. Something like this will do you:

```
static string asciiOctets2String( byte[] bytes )
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length);
  foreach ( char c in bytes.Select( b => (char) b ) )
  {
    switch ( c )
    {
    case '\u0000' : sb.Append("<NUL>") ; break ;
    case '\u0001' : sb.Append("<SOH>") ; break ;
    case '\u0002' : sb.Append("<STX>") ; break ;
    case '\u0003' : sb.Append("<ETX>") ; break ;
    case '\u0004' : sb.Append("<EOT>") ; break ;
    case '\u0005' : sb.Append("<ENQ>") ; break ;
    case '\u0006' : sb.Append("<ACK>") ; break ;
    case '\u0007' : sb.Append("<BEL>") ; break ;
    case '\u0008' : sb.Append("<BS>" ) ; break ;
    case '\u0009' : sb.Append("<HT>" ) ; break ;
    case '\u000A' : sb.Append("<LF>" ) ; break ;
    case '\u000B' : sb.Append("<VT>" ) ; break ;
    case '\u000C' : sb.Append("<FF>" ) ; break ;
    case '\u000D' : sb.Append("<CR>" ) ; break ;
    case '\u000E' : sb.Append("<SO>" ) ; break ;
    case '\u000F' : sb.Append("<SI>" ) ; break ;
    case '\u0010' : sb.Append("<DLE>") ; break ;
    case '\u0011' : sb.Append("<DC1>") ; break ;
    case '\u0012' : sb.Append("<DC2>") ; break ;
    case '\u0013' : sb.Append("<DC3>") ; break ;
    case '\u0014' : sb.Append("<DC4>") ; break ;
    case '\u0015' : sb.Append("<NAK>") ; break ;
    case '\u0016' : sb.Append("<SYN>") ; break ;
    case '\u0017' : sb.Append("<ETB>") ; break ;
    case '\u0018' : sb.Append("<CAN>") ; break ;
    case '\u0019' : sb.Append("<EM>" ) ; break ;
    case '\u001A' : sb.Append("<SUB>") ; break ;
    case '\u001B' : sb.Append("<ESC>") ; break ;
    case '\u001C' : sb.Append("<FS>" ) ; break ;
    case '\u001D' : sb.Append("<GS>" ) ; break ;
    case '\u001E' : sb.Append("<RS>" ) ; break ;
    case '\u001F' : sb.Append("<US>" ) ; break ;
    case '\u007F' : sb.Append("<DEL>") ; break ;
    default :
      if ( c > '\u007F' )
      {
        sb.AppendFormat( @"\u{0:X4}" , (ushort)c ) ; // in ASCII, any octet in the range 0x80-0xFF doesn't have a character glyph associated with it
      }
      else
      {
        sb.Append( c ) ;
      }
      break ;
    }
  }
  return sb.ToString() ;
}
```

Or another approach, probably faster than a switch and probably faster than a dictionary-based approach, but not as readable:

```
private static string[] controlChars =
{
  "<NUL>" , "<SOH>" , "<STX>" , "<ETX>" ,
  "<EOT>" , "<ENQ>" , "<ACK>" , "<BEL>" ,
  "<BS>"  , "<HT>"  , "<LF>"  , "<VT>"  ,
  "<FF>"  , "<CR>"  , "<SO>"  , "<SI>"  ,
  "<DLE>" , "<DC1>" , "<DC2>" , "<DC3>" ,
  "<DC4>" , "<NAK>" , "<SYN>" , "<ETB>" ,
  "<CAN>" , "<EM>"  , "<SUB>" , "<ESC>" ,
  "<FS>"  , "<GS>"  , "<RS>"  , "<US>"  ,
} ;
static string asciiOctets2String( byte[] bytes )
{
  StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(bytes.Length);
  foreach ( char c in bytes.Select( b => (char) b ) )
  {
    if      ( c <  '\u0020' ) { sb.Append( controlChars[c] ) ; }
    else if ( c == '\u007F' ) { sb.Append( "<DEL>"         ) ; }
    else if ( c >  '\u007F' ) { sb.AppendFormat( @"\u{0:X4}" , (ushort)c ) ; }
    else /* 0x20-0x7E */      { sb.Append( c ) ; }
  }
  return sb.ToString() ;
}
```

Comment: What about characters \u0010 through \u0020? I think you'll want those. . . Or did you just leave them out for brevity?

Comment: @JimMischel...that'll teach me to get distracted. Added the missing codes. If I'd left them out for brevity, I'd have inserted an ellipsis (...) to indicate the omission. Left out U+0020 since that's the space character. Easy to put it in if you want it explicitly shown.

Comment: @ClausJørgensen: it doesn't do the same thing. Per the documentation, "ASCII characters are limited to the lowest 128 Unicode characters, from U+0000 to U+007F...characters outside that range are replaced with a question mark (?) before the encoding operation is performed." Not the same semantics at all. Moreover, the problem as stated by the OP requires scanning individual characters/bytes one way or another: this kills the two birds with one stone.

Comment: I ran your solution through a gambit of tests first... it passes :) I only changed the condition of if it is greater than 0x7F to append a '?' Thank you. I'm going to time yours against the other solution and see what i get.

Answer (score 8):

You'll have to create a table of what you want the control character to be, for example:

```
Dictionary<byte, string> controlCodes = new Dictionary<byte, string>
{
    { 0x00, "<NUL>" },
    { 0x01, "<SOH>" },
    { 0x02, "<STX>" },
    { 0x03, "<ETX>" },
    ...
}
```

You can use [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C0_Controls_and_Basic_Latin) to build the full list.

Then building your would be as simple as:

```
var output = String.Join(
    string.Empty, 
    array.Select(b => 
        controlCodes.ContainsKey(b) 
        ? controlCodes[b]
        : Encoding.ASCII.GetString(new[] { b })));
```

Of course this could be improved significantly. Something like this would be a bit more efficient:

```
string str = string.Empty;
int i = 0, j = 0;
while (i < array.Length && j > -1)
{
    j = Array.FindIndex(array, i, b => controlCodes.ContainsKey(b));
    if (j > -1) 
    {
        if (j > i)
        {
            str += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(array, i, j - i);
        }

        str += controlCodes[array[j]];
        i = j + 1;
    }
    else 
    {
        str += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(array, i, array.Length - i);
    }
}

return str;
```

Comment: I'd probably change that last line to `new string((char)b, 1)`. Other than that, I really like this solution. Although I guess you could just create an array of 256 strings and directly index it ... Naw. That's just crazy optimization for no good purpose.

Comment: I too like this solution. I'm going to load up NUnit and run a few simulations on it and verify that it gives me almost (if not entirely) what i was looking for. Thank you for this. I'm very new to extension methods and LINQ and WPF (sometimes I feel a little overwhelmed, but I'm pushing my self to learn)

Comment: I've tried the second more efficient way and I am getting a few errors with my test. The first method works great. I'll edit my post with my tests

Comment: @RobertSnyder At a glance, I can see I made a typo on the second call to `GetString`. `array.Length - 1` should have been `array.Length - i`. Let me know if this satisfies the test cases now. If not, I'll look a bit deeper to see if there's some logical flaw somewhere.

Comment: @p.s.w.g it indeed does fix the tests. I spent a few minutes on that last one to try and figure out what was wrong with it. my thought was to put i++ in a few places. I didn't study the code super hard. I do like your 2 answers, but in the end I ran each test 3 time taking the average and yours were 2ms and 11ms slower. Not that it is a big deal in my context, but I might be using this to log communication between my hardware and software and need it to perform in less than 300ms (which it is already at 220ms)